# WPF why is TextBox in WrapPanel is cutted

Tags: wpf

XAML:

```
<WrapPanel>
        <TextBox  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  AcceptsReturn="True"/>
        <TextBox  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

As you can see at the following picture, the second TextBox is cut after it wrapped, to second line.
Picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the markup for your screenshots?

Comment: i really put XAML, but for some reason it was dropped..., anyway, i edited the question

Comment: Did you see my answer? You need to put a ScrollViewer around the WrapPanel.

Comment: yes, thank you, but i do not want a Scroller for the WrapPanel, only for the children (TxtBox, DataGrid etc... )

Answer (score 0):

Put the `WrapPanel` in a `ScrollViewer` if you want to be able to scroll its content:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBox Width="400"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="500" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"></TextBox>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

The `WrapPanel` won't automatically adopt to the size of the window.